# Long polling causing huge delay

Tags: php, ajax, comet

I am using long polling to check if there is any new incoming data.I am facing a problem when one request is waiting for a response the other requests are not being processed until this one completes.I am using jQuery Ajax post method and async = true.Can anyone help me with this.I think my requests are getting queued until the previous one timesout.

Comment: Please narrow down the problem to one technology. This is very broad atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a problem with the ajax or javascript. It is your php locking the session. You need to add `session_write_close();` to the php that is running on your long poll.